# Is there a plugin that provides a new text element that works on single AND double quotes?

Tags: custom-text-object, quote

I have a common task which is refactoring typescript import statements. However sometimes the quotes used for the dependency path are single quotes and sometimes double quotes. this means when i go through my list and want to use `.` repeat to repeat the `ci"` action, if the next item is single quoted I am screwed and it will not repeat, because it is looking for double quotes.

So I hope there is something out there that works with repeat (or will it require tpope/vim-repeat? I don't know) that can match both single and double quotes? I would use `q` for quote for it. And I would love if it could work on even more char classes too like javascript template string backtick quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define you own `iq` text object with the following commands:

```
vnoremap iq ?['"]^Mlo/['"]^Mh
omap iq :normal viq<CR>
```

Where `^M` is obtained by hitting <kbd>Ctrl v</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Or simply:

```
vnoremap iq ?['"]<CR>lo/['"]<CR>h
omap iq :normal viq<CR>
```

I don't know any Vim plugin that define such Text Object but if you are using Neovim you could use the `iq` Text Object provided by [nvim-various-textobjs](https://github.com/chrisgrieser/nvim-various-textobjs).

Comment: very interesting, thank you, if this works as expected this looks like a powerful way to define anything a regex could match!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. If it solves you problem I'll be glad if you could accept the solution. It allow the question to rest (but take your time to verify that it works for you ;-) ) :-)

Comment: Not had time to test it yet and it is an admittedly rare use case. But I'll accept and come back to revoke it and comment if I encounter issues.